# C# Windows Form Chart control - binding multiple y values from csv file

Tags: c#, csv, data-binding, charts

This is my first exposure to data-binding, so I have very little knowledge of all of the properties and methods involved. I want to bind multiple series to a csv file where the column 1 is a DateTime, and columns 2 through N are doubles. I started from the example in the WinFormsChartSamples for binding a single Y value to the csv; however, do not believe I am understanding the way to bind multiple Y values.

The original code:

```
string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + file;
string ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
path + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\"";

OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

// create a database command on the connection using query
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

// open the connection
myCommand.Connection.Open();

// create a database reader
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

// column 1 is a time value, column 2 is a double
// databind the reader to the chart using the DataBindXY method
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "1", myReader, "2");
```

The following works:

```
myCommand.Connection.Open();
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "1", myReader, "2");

myCommand.Connection.Open();
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "1", myReader, "3");

myCommand.Connection.Open();
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
chart1.Series[2].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "1", myReader, "4");
```

I could put the above into a loop and iterate over all of the Series, but surely there is a better way than reading through the csv file multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did find a better way:

```
string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + file;
string ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path +
";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\"";

OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

chart1.DataSource = myCommand;

for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series.Count; i++) {
    chart1.Series[i].XValueMember = "1";
    chart1.Series[i].YValueMembers = (i+2).ToString();
}
chart1.DataBind();
```

Perhaps this will help someone else...